# FInding relative path in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code in a perl module,

```
package Foo;
our $pathToScript = "/home/Lucas/project841/python_script.py";
```

It is frequently called by other modules in the same file directory through

```
$output = `$Foo::pathToScript`;
# etc
```

I would like to remove the hard coding of the actual path and use relative path, Eg. ./python_script.py to call the script from other modules.

What would be the ideal way?

Answer (score 0):

You said your Perl script is "frequently" called from the same directory where the Python script resides, not "always".  If you remove the absolute path, you'll need to change that "frequently" to "always", and just change `$pathToScript` to the Python script name (no path).

You could also consider setting the environment PATH (in the Perl script) so that the Python script (without the full path in `$pathToScript`) is *always* found, regardless of where the user is running from or where the Perl script is located.

Comment: Hi, I don't get quite get you on frequently vs always. Nonetheless, I have tried adding but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried printing the current directory of whichever Perl module that calls it, but it's pointing to /home/Lucas even though the Perl module does not reside there.

Comment: If you intend to always distribute the Perl Module (*.pm file) with the Python script, and want the PM to be able to find the PY wherever they are stored (not always in `/home/lucas`), have a look at this for determining the path to a PM (from the calling PL script), and then the PL script would call the PY script using the full path.  http://www.symkat.com/find-a-perl-modules-path

Comment: Hi. I tend to distribute the entire folder with consist of both *.pm and .py file in the same directory.